# Moving a cell in a collection view beyond the last cell of another section does not work

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uigesturerecognizer

To be able to move/pan a cell in a collection view, a UIGestureRecognizer should be implemented. This works fine in a single-section collection view. However, in a multi-section collection view an error occurs when a cell is panned/moved beyond the last cell of another section.
Although “cellForItemAtIndexPath” is correctly triggered to display “new” cells during panning, it should NOT be triggered after panning beyond the last available cell (i.e. in that situation indexPath.row == numberOfItemsInSection and results in an error (see code below) ).

In a table view, this problem does not occur with the (default) moving/panning implementation.

Could this be a bug in Swift and does anyone have suggestions to avoid the trigger to “cellForItemAtIndexPath” during panning beyond the last cell in a section?

Below is a working code example in Swift 2.3 to illustrate the problem.

```
class CustomViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    private var list = ["one", "two", "three","four","five","six","seven","eight"]
    private var itemsList: [[String]]!

    private var collectionView : UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        itemsList = [list, list, list] // Create three sections

        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRectZero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
        self.collectionView.dataSource = self
        self.collectionView.delegate = self
        self.collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.collectionView.registerClass(CustomCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")

        let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(CustomViewController.handleGesture(_:)))
        self.collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
        self.view.addSubview(self.collectionView)
    }

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        let margins = view.layoutMarginsGuide
        self.collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(margins.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).active = true
        self.collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(margins.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).active = true
        self.collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).active = true
        self.collectionView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.topAnchor, constant: 0).active = true
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int   {
        return itemsList.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
         return itemsList[section].count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell

        let items = itemsList[indexPath.section]

        cell.label.text = items[indexPath.row] // The error occurs here, after panning beyond the last cell of another section stating: "fatal error: Index out of range"
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, canMoveItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let itemToMove = itemsList[sourceIndexPath.section][sourceIndexPath.row]
        itemsList[sourceIndexPath.section].removeAtIndex(sourceIndexPath.row)
        itemsList[destinationIndexPath.section].insert(itemToMove, atIndex: destinationIndexPath.row)
    }


    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
                  return CGSizeMake(collectionView.bounds.size.width, 50)
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSizeMake(collectionView.bounds.size.width, 40)
    }

    func handleGesture(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        switch(gesture.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerState.Began:

            guard let selectedIndexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(gesture.locationInView(self.collectionView)) else {
                break }
            collectionView.beginInteractiveMovementForItemAtIndexPath(selectedIndexPath)
        case UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed:
            collectionView.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(gesture.locationInView(gesture.view!))
        case UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended:
            collectionView.endInteractiveMovement()
        default:
            collectionView.cancelInteractiveMovement()
        }
    }
}


class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var label: UILabel!
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.label = UILabel()
        self.label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.contentView.addSubview(self.label)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        let margins = self.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        self.label.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(margins.leadingAnchor).active = true
        self.label.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(margins.trailingAnchor).active = true
        self.label.centerYAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.contentView.centerYAnchor).active = true
    }
}
```

Comment: "an error occurs" What error? You say "the problem occurs here", but _you_ are the one throwing a `fatalError`. So what is the _problem_?

Comment: The error occurs when `indexPath.row > itemsList[indexPath.section].count` , which results after panning a cell beyond the last cell in another section. I updated the code.

Comment: But now I don't know what line the error is on. Do you mean `let items = itemsList[indexPath.section]`? So did you debug and see what `indexPath.section` actually is?

Comment: The error occurs at `items[indexPath.row]`. IndexPath is `<NSIndexPath: ...> {length = 2, path = 1 - 8}` just before the error occurs. With this indexPath the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` should have never been triggered. Therefore, I feel that it might be a bug.

Comment: Maybe try preventing it from being triggered with your `targetIndexPathForMoveFromItem` implementation?

Comment: That's a good suggestion but before a cell is moved in `moveItemAtIndexPath`, `cellForItemAtIndexPath` is already incorrectly triggered. It is really strange since `indexPath.row` should ALWAYS be < `itemsList[indexPath.section].count` but that does not seem to be here.

Comment: I'm not talking about `moveItemAtIndexPath`. I'm talking about `targetIndexPathForMoveFromItem`, for which you seem to have no implementation. I'm saying you should try making one. I have no idea if it will solve the problem, but it can't hurt to try it. https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618052-collectionview

Comment: Yes, I tried without success.  `targetIndexPathForMoveFromItem` seems  not able to block a call to `cellForItemAtIndexPath` since it can only prevent dropping a cell to a specific indexPath. Nevertheless, I really appreciate your help. Do you possibly have other suggestions? Or might it really be a bug in Swift?

Comment: I'm sorry it's not working. The only other thing I can think of is to check, in code, in `cellForRow`, whether this is a valid index path for your model. If not, you're going to have to return _something_ even if it is just an empty cell; you are not allowed to return `nil` here. I do not know what the visible effect of this will be (because I don't understand why `cellForRow` is even being called during the drag).

Comment: When I place `guard indexPath.row < itemsList[indexPath.section].count else { return cell }` in `cellForRow` it does continue panning now, but when I release the panning cell it is dropped one row above the expected location. It is at least better than an error, but not really what the user would expect...

Comment: The issue appeared to be a bug in iOS, but seems resolved with xcode 8 GM. I will therefore put that as an answer below. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Apple the issue described in my question was a bug in iOS, and seems resolved in the current release of iOS 10 beta (xcode 8 GM).

Unfortunately, other issues with collection views are not fixed yet, such as basic support to move items to empty sections.